# Socket.IO and latency

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

Building a NodeJS-Socket-IO application that streams a HD video feed from a Kinect device to a browser. There is roughly a half second of latency which is acceptable for my purpose. However, every so often this latency balloons to several seconds, but can't figure out why.

Could this have something to do with the specific connection that Socket-IO is negotiating? As I understand it Sacket-IO will choose the best connection depending on the current conditions.

Any other tips to reduce this bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

It's completely normal for connections to have spikes in latency.  The problem with your approach is that data will never get dropped since it is over a nice and reliable TCP connection.  You will have to figure out how to handle that in your application, likely by dropping buffers of data at times convenient for your codec.

For your comment about choosing the best connection... this has to do with compatibility, and not with latency or anything else.

Get friendly with a packet sniffer like Wireshark to see exactly what is happening when these spikes occur.  Your application should expect, and be able to handle, extreme spikes of perceived latency.  These will occur if packets are lost and re-transmitted.

The best thing to do would be to use an existing technology such as WebRTC that handles all of this for you, with low latency.

Comment: hmmm. will investigate switching to a nodejs-webRTC solution. thanks